# Create function without using type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I am new in Scala and I have a doubt.

Imagine this situation: a function that verifies if what is passed has any digit, without cycles, var or val, declarations or recursion. This function is named as hasDigit and must be declared without using type parameters.

```
def hasDigit.... ???
```

Can someone explain me this please?

What I have so far:

```
def hasDigit(element: => Any) = element.toString.toList.exists(x => x.isDigit)
```

I can't understand if the function above is a function without type parameters or not. 
I  could do this:

```
 def hasDigit_[T](element: T) = element.toString.toList.exists(x => x.isDigit)
```

But in this exercise it is supposed to create a generic function (what i've already done) and create a function without type parameters (that's what I want to achieve with my first function and I dont know if it is correct)

Comment: The question is unclear; Please define `hasDigit` more accurately (what's the input - a `String`? What's the output - a `Boolean`?) and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Exacly, this question is unclear and i am  trying to understand it. The return type is boolean and this is what I have for now: def hasDigit(element: => Any) = element.toString.toList.exists(x => x.isDigit)

Comment: First, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49160689/edit) button to add this info (the code you tried) to the post. Second - what are you asking? Do you want the _solution_ to this question (if so - detail what's wrong with _your_ solution) or just the terminology in the original question (which was copied from somewhere) clarified? Generally speaking, posts with just "help me understand this" won't get good answers here - if you have a _specific_ question about Scala (e.g. what are type parameters) or about why your solution fails (e.g. "I get this error: ..."), state it clearly.

Comment: Sure, my appologies. This question is an exercise from my school and I am trying to figure it out. I don't know what is a function without type parameters. There were two alternatives to this, one was creating a generic function (what i've already done), and the other one was this function, without type parameters. My actual code is with or without type parameters?

Comment: I've edited with more information know and I am so sorry. I think know I could express what I want.

Comment: @AndréAzevedo "type parameters" are those funny variables in square brackets. Do you see any square brackets in your first function definition?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin No, I don't, but I see an "Any". Can it be considered as a type?

Comment: @AndréAzevedo Of course `Any` is a type (it's the [top type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html)). But it's not a "type parameter". Types of ordinary value parameters of a function and [type parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) are two separate concepts.

Comment: That’a what I wanted to ear! Thank you, now I understood!